# How to Get 3 Nodes using AS3 and E4X?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, e4x

I am writing a class in Main.as that makes a urlRequest and returns the result.  There are 3 nodes I need, minTemp, maxTemp and Icon. I'm making the request for one city so there should be just one occurrence of these nodes.  How would I structure the AS3 to grab these nodes and their values?

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

public function Main() {

        var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://myurl");
        var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        var result:XmlDocument=new XMLDocument();

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

        result.ignorWhite=true;
        result.parseXML(getXMLString());
        }
}
```

I'm getting errors 1046 XmlDocument type was not found, 1120 access of undefined property parseXML, and 1180 call to possibly undefined method getXMLString.  How would I clear those up as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define the function parseXMl and result is not created either, this way should work:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {    
        public function Main() {

                var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://myurl");
            var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoaded);
            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

        }

        private function onXmlLoaded(event : Event) : void
        {
            XML.ignoreWhitespace= true;
            var urlLoader : URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
            var resultXML : XML = XML(urlLoader.data);
            trace(resultXML);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SidC this answer will fix your errors. If you also need help with parsing your XML, show it please.

Comment: @SidC trace(resultXML.minTemp);trace(resultXML.maxTemp);trace(resultXML.Icon);

Comment: Thanks to all.  My syntax errors are resolved. When I debug the movie, I receive "Cannot display source code at this location." I added @George Profenza 's three trace statements initially, same error, then commented them out.  Ideas?